# Resource on free conformal field theory

Tags: resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory, education

In QFT, it is easy to find resource on a free scalar quantum field theory. When I tried to search for a free conformal field theory, I could not find a good resource.

Can anyone either give some information with regards to how free conformal field theory would look like, or give some links that would help?

Comment: $2$d - di Francesco et al.; Blumenhagen et al. $\geq3$d - Slava Rychkov EFPL lectures.

Comment: For an easy introduction to CFT I'd suggest [Paul Ginsparg lessons](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9108028); they helped me a lot while approaching the matter.